# Avoid Postbacks using Webservices and Webmethods

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm working with an ERP project. I want to avoid all postbacks in the page. I decided to use webservices or webmethods to avoid these postback issues. One another advantage i see- Its possible to get the inner html contents of the  elements too via javascript.

I'm not using any third party controls in my page. **Whats the better method to create a page without postbacks and to make UI so attractive. Is Telrik controls advisable for this purpose?**

Comment: Why you want to avoid postback? what problem are you facing with postback?

Comment: I want to avoid page reloading.. I want to add new columns to table using jQuery... if I do so I want to get values from the newly added textboxes via JavaScript. I can send this only using a webmethod. is it efficient to do so? what are the metjods adopted in asp to avoid page reload while postback

Comment: You can use jquery ajax's get or post method to perform these operations. They will not reload the page and it is efficient/faster. Also, you can pass ajax call to any .cs,.vb,.ashx etc.

Comment: I'm not much familiar with jquery's ajax. What about calling via webmethods using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the methods I know of so far:

Basic Assumption: You are using ASP.NET web forms.

1. The [one](http://jquery-with-asp.net/2011/07/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net/) (I assume) you are using. (Which is good AFAIK.) [More details here..](http://www.packtpub.com/article/making-ajax-calls-using-jquery)
2. Wrapping the page in an update panel. (Use this with [care](http://www.nerdswithlives.com/2008/12/updatepanel-slow-performance-ajax.html).
   Performance overheads may show up if the page is heavy. [Decide for
   yourself.](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/))
3. Telerik controls on the other hand, is quite a good tool set if you can part with some money for it. (My humble opinion.)

Comment: Using webservices or webmethods are better then? But I'm feeling Telrik controls are not so flexible or much learning curve required for much flexibility.

Comment: I went through the site you mentioned. But one doubt, why Json is used for server side communication. I think the method is built in. We can simply call the webmethod as PageMethods.Mymethod() in javascript ?

Comment: `jquery` ajax calls usually take their `url` as: Page.aspx\MyMethod for ASP.NET web forms and what better way to communicate between ASP.NET and client-side javascript than JSON?

Comment: This is how I called when I required it once.      PageMethods.GetServerResponse(id, dragid, dragidParnet.id, OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);  Why all those codes there??? Sorry If I asked any blunder!

Comment: @SubinJacob, I have updated the link in the answer with a simpler example: http://jquery-with-asp.net/2011/07/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net/. The site:http://jquery-with-asp.net has a lot of simple examples on how to use jquery ajax with ASP.NET.